# Convert String array value to byte Value in Java- Marshalling

Tags: java, xml, csv, marshalling

We have a program that convert `CSV` to `XML` file with Marshaling.

The issue is that come of the files in the XML elements are type of byte or Short.

For example I have a `String` value that is equal to `0` in my CSV file that need to be convert to `byte` value as `0`

This is my Code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xmlFileList.get(i).toString()));  //get csv file separately

 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {   
 String[] value = line.split(";"); 

Book.setBookNumber(value[12].getBytes());
```

Here is my Book Class

```
public class Book {

  private String BookName;
  private byte[] BookNumber;


public byte[] getBookNumber() {
    return bn;
  }

 public void setBookNumber(byte[] bn) {
    this.BookNumber = bn;
  }
}
```

SetBookNumber in my `Book` class has been defined as `byte[]`.

The value of my `value[12]` is `0`, if I define it as `String` there is no issue, but if I define it as `byte[]` it does not return me `0`, instead it returns me `MA==`

`value[12]` should be as a `byte` type, since in `XSD` it defined as a `byte`

Below you can find a sample line of my CSV file.

`Alex Brown,,NewBook,,2018,Road,Egidio Carella,41,Second, 033033,,0,0,0,3,028000909777700,0,1,3,590 ,0 ,0 ,0`

As you can see in the row sample, all the value with 0 and 1 should be change to byte type.
Can anyone help me how can I do it?

Comment: please share the Book.java (pojo class) and expected xml output

Comment: Hi Lakshan, Thanks for your reply, I modified the question. the output of my XMLis correct completely, I mean the structure is completely right. but I create all these classes based on the XSD that we has. For the one that all elements are type of String I have no problem, but for the one that some types are String, some Date, some byte, I have issue.

Comment: in your case, BookNumber is appeared as `MA==` in your output xml file. but your requirement, it should be a `0`?

Comment: yes Lakshan, exactly, I mean the data in my CSV is ```0```, but when I define my BookNumber as ```byte[]``` type, and set the value as ```value[12].getBytes()```, in generated XML file instead of ```0``` , I see ```MA==```

Comment: if you can please share csv file content (single data row that relevant to this question)

Comment: Hello Lakshan, I updated it! Thanks again

Comment: did u solve @sinaei ?